# How to plot a boundary in matplotlib 2D pcolor plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using data stored in I have 2D regions that I plot in the following way:

```
for k in data['blks']:
     x = data[k]['x'] 
     y = data[k]['y']
     ro= data[k][Q]
     p=ax.pcolor(x, y, ro)
     # plot the boundary enclosed by x,y
```

How do I plot each of the boundary regions enclosed by x and y? These are not rectangles so simply figuring out min and max won't work. is there a function to plot just the edges of each of the enclosed regions?

The new figure (after commenting the call to pcolor) would produce something like this:

[image]